# Changing iframe src with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to change my iframe src and reload the iframe with the following code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#changeframe').click(function () {
  $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
  });
</script>


<input type="button" id="changeframe" value="Change">

<iframe id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

When I click "Change" on the button nothing happens. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If the code is as it is in your example, you need to wrap the jQuery in `$(function() { ... });` since the button does not exist when the script runs

Comment: Rearrange the order. Script go last and try again :) - #changeframe doesn't exist yet in your current order.

Comment: Maybe jQuery is being run before the browser knows of those elements... hence the dom ready function? which you don't seem to be using...

Comment: do you have the input button inside the form tag ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order does matter.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="changeframe" value="Change">

<iframe id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%" ></iframe>

// Go Last since changeframe hasn't exist yet.
<script>
  $('#changeframe').click(function () {
      $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This works thank you, is is possible to use a text link instead of the button?

Comment: Yes since it is just onclick. I suggest upgrade your jQuery since version 1.11.1 is ancient :P

Comment: However 1.11 is still compatible with IE<11

Comment: @Noobit how would the link looks like? Right now I have but to no avail                                                                     <a onclick="changeframe" id="again">Change</a>

Answer (score 0):

1. If the code is as it is in your example, you need to wrap the jQuery in
   `$(function() { ... });` or move it below the html since the button
   does not exist when the script runs
2. Look in the console. You MAY not be allowed to change the src of an iframe containing a url from another domain - some browsers like IE can throw a security exception. You could have access denied in the console
3. Some websites do not allow their pages to be framed. It is not the case in your example but would for example give errors if you try to load google in a frame

```js
$(function() {
  $('#changeframe').click(function() {
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" id="changeframe" value="Change">

<iframe id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Using a link - no need for jQuery (same if the button above was submitting a form, target iframename):

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="declinedframe">Change</a>

<iframe name="declinedframe" id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%"></iframe>
```

If you MUST use jQuery for the link give it the ID of changeframe use

```
$(function() {
  $('#changeframe').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', this.href );
  });
});
```

Comment: Number 2 isn't true.

Comment: @Noobit I have changed to "may" since some browsers do not like changing the src of an already loaded frame for security reasons

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which browsers stop you from changing an iframe element that exist on your page? It's not stupid IE is it? o_O

Comment: Yes - I have not tested IE11 or Edge but older IEs would not allow any manipulation of an iframe that had been loaded from a different domain. Makes sense from a security spoofing point of view